# Creating new rows for each group using values from first row of group

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need to create a new row for each group of a grouped tibble based on values from the first row of each group.

I am trying to use do(add_row()) to create the new row and use top_n to access the value from the first row of each group.

```
df = tibble(ID = rep(1:2, each = 2), x = rep(1:2, each = 2), y = seq(1:4))
gb_df <- group_by(df, ID, x)

new_df <- gb_df %>% do(add_row(., ID = top_n(.,1, wt=y)[,"ID"], x = 0, y = 
top_n(.,1, wt=y)[,"y"]-1, .before=0))
```

However I get the following error message.

```
Error: Columns `ID`, `y` must be 1d atomic vectors or lists
```

I want the following output.

```
> new_df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0
2     1     4     1
3     1     4     2
4     2     0     2
5     2     5     3
6     2     5     4
```

Comment: Not clear. Where is the added row? Why did the other rows change values?

Comment: In `tibble` to get a vector use `top_n(x,1, wt=y)[["y"]]` instead of `top_n(x,1, wt=y)[, "y"]`

Comment: @A.Suliman your suggestion worked for `ID` but not `y`. It seems I cannot do math on the returned vector.

Comment: @AmyMoody, `gb_df %>% do(add_row(., ID = top_n(.,1, wt=y)[["ID"]], x = 0, y = top_n(.,1, wt=y)[["y"]]-1, .before=0))` works fine for me.

Comment: `top_n` gets the largest N values. Maybe you want `slice(1)`, which gets the *first* row

Comment: Thank you @camille, that was the issue